# How to get value from array of arrays

Tags: swift, dynamic-arrays

I have array of arrays `grid` in my code. what I want to do is checking if there is a object at `x`, `y` `let object = grid[x][y]` if `object` is not `nil` I edit it else I assign a new object to it `grid[x][y] = newObject()`.

```
if let object = grid[x][y] {
   object.property = newValue
} else {
   grid[x][y] = newObject()
}
```

but I get `fatal error: Array index out of range` in the line `if let object = grid[x][y] {`

what is the best way to do that? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us how you are allocating the `grid` array. Almost certainly it is not allocated to be the size you "expect". It will also have to be an array of `Object?` not `Object`. Arrays do not return `nil` if the indices are out of bounds.

Comment: The allocation of the `grid` is `var grid = [[Object!]]()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, if you want to modify your `grid` object down the road, you can't define it with `let`. You must use `var`.

It looks like you're trying to use optional binding (`if let x = Optional(y) { ... }`) with array subscripting (`array[x]`). This won't work, as an array subscript doesn't return an optional. It'll instead return a valid object or throw an exception. You could try this:

```
if grid.count > x {
  if grid[x].count > y {
    object = grid[x][y]
  }
}
```

Comment: It's called `count` in Swift, not `length`

Comment: Nice catch, @Kametrixom. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ blerch Thanks for the answer. That is what I was missing.

Comment: No problem, @Ismail. :)

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do (as I said in my comment) is to both allocate the array to the size that you want, and to make it an array of `Object?` rather than `Object` (or `Object!` - why do you do that?). Something like this, for a 2x2 array ...

```
var grid = [[Object?]](count:2, repeatedValue: [Object?](count:2, repeatedValue:nil))
```

Comment: I don't know the size in advance I want it to be mutable. about `Object` or `Object` I am not sure about it. So I will use `Object?` as you mentioned.

Comment: I just found an other problem in this. When I check for Object in the keys [x,y] if I didn't found one I create it and add `grid[x][y] = Object()` but x, y can be any numbers.i.e I may want to add the first Object `grid[1][999] = Object()`

Comment: It sounds like you shouldn't be using an array, then, if you can't say what the dimensions will be. Consider using a `Dictionary`, instead, using the indices as your keys.

Comment: I will do that. Thanks @Grimxn.